# Is there a ctags option for vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, ctags

How to jump to a vimscript file's function definition?

(I'm having a hard time searching for this particular functionality, then getting results for using ctags in Vim, and not sure how to phrase that properly...)

Comment: Maybe could you be more specific. Give a example of the definition you are searching, what you have done to find the definition, how it fails. This would give us more hint about what is blocking you.

Comment: To add context, ctags generates a tags file. I believe OP is asking how this can be done by extending support for ctags to vimscript. See https://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html

Comment: Do you specifically want to use ctags, as suggested by the question title? Or do you just want to be able to jump to a Vimscript function definition, (which seems to be implied by the question's body)?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the search in file functionality of Vim to find the definition of the function.

To find the definition of `MyFunction` I would run the command:

```
:vim "^fun.* MyFunction"
```

Or using the [Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) plugin:

```
:Ack! "^fun.* MyFunction"
```

To use tags you have to be sure first that the `tags` files has been generated in the current directory for the project in which you are searching the function definition.

You can achieve that by running `ctags` explicitly:

```
:!ctags *.vim
```

Or if you prefer skip the console output to check the result

```
:silent! !ctags *.vim
```

Or by making sure a plugin such as [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) running it in the background for you.

With this ensured you can go to the definition using the command:

```
:tjump MyFunction
```

Comment: @husB, I have added some more information about how to generate tags.

Comment: universal ctags supports the "Vim" language. Also I think you mean `:silent! !ctags …`

Comment: Thanks for spoting the mistake :-)